# Custom SonarQube plugin activated at server startup

Tags: plugins, widget, ldap, sonarqube

I developed a custom SonarQube widget as a plugin which is able to synchronize the LDAP groups to the SonarQube database when the user press a button. source:
https://github.com/bakaibalazs/SonarQube-LDAPGroup-Synchronizer

I would like to execute this synchronization process every time when the server starts up. Is it possible? What is the preferred way to code is as a custom extension?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible and should be implemented using the specific ServerExtension [ServerStartHandler](http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/5.1.2/apidocs/org/sonar/api/platform/ServerStartHandler.html).